# Can IIS 6.0 show server status just like tomcat

Tags: c#, iis, tomcat, cpu

the server status might contain: CPU Usage, Memory Usage and other server's status data.
any recommendations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx); you can set it in Report mode and select the counters you want to look at. :-)